# How to select an element with jq in a nested JSON

Tags: json, jq

I have input like this:

```
"data": [{
        "id": 111585,
        "name": "Inverter",
        "batList": [{
            "name": "Battery1",
            "dataDict": [{
                "key": "b1_1",
                "name": "Battery V.",
                "value": 57.63,
                "unit": "V"
            }, {
                "key": "b1_2",
                "name": "Battery I.",
                "value": -0.10,
                "unit": "A"
            }, {
                "key": "b1_3",
                "name": "Battery P.",
                "value": -6,
                "unit": "W"
            }, {
                "key": "b1_4",
                "name": "Inner T.",
                "value": 25,
                "unit": "℃"
            }, {
                "key": "b1_5",
                "name": "Remaining Capacity % ",
                "value": 99,
                "unit": "%"
            }]
        }]
    }],
```

from which I want to extract the 'value' property (i.e. 99) for "Remaining Capacity % ".

My best amateurish but well searched attempt is

```
jq --arg instance "Remaining Capacity % " '.data | .[] | select(.name == $instance) | .value')
```

but I get an empty result. Any help with this nested intransigence would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea seems about right, but you missed out mentioning the top-level paths after `.data[]`, it should have been

```
jq --arg instance "Remaining Capacity % " \
     '.data[].batList[].dataDict[] | select(.name == $instance ).value' json
```

Comment: Works! I must have tried every combination around your solution expect the right one. I was getting jq: error Cannot index array with string most time I tried batList[] etc.. Thanks for your prompt help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Inian's answer is to use the select-contains recipe, e.g.:

```
jq -r '.[].batList[].dataDict[] | select(.name|contains("Remaining")).value' file
```

While no better in this example, it is handy to remember especially if you need to find a bunch of values, e.g. `contains("Battery")` would return three results.